# Which ones should I use on Android instead of normal Java

Tags: java, android, insert, jtextfield

I'm new to Android programming; I made couple programs about simple table which is just works for "Getting data from database and show it on table" or "Save the texts which is in jtextfields to database". So I need to do this on Android but I think my knowledge doesn't work at all on Android. How should I do this on Android?

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
public class YeniUye extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection conn=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    PreparedStatement pst=null;



    /**
     * Creates new form YeniUye
     */
    public YeniUye() {
        initComponents();
    conn=javaconnect.ConnecrDb();
         Update_table();




    }

    private void Update_table(){


    try{
    String sql ="select * from YeniUyeFrame ";
   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   rs=pst.executeQuery();
   yeniuyetable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));


}
catch(Exception e){
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


}finally{
try{
pst.close();
rs.close();
}catch(Exception e){
}
}





}    




    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        yeniuyeepostatxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        yeniuyeyastxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        yeniuyeisimtxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        yeniuyetable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        cmd_save = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cmd_save1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cmd_save2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cmd_save3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        cmd_save4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        jLabel2.setText("Yaş");

        jLabel1.setText("İsim");

        jLabel4.setText("E-Posta");

        jLabel5.setText("Katılım Tarihi");

        yeniuyeepostatxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 153));

        yeniuyeyastxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 153));

        yeniuyeisimtxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 153));
        yeniuyeisimtxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                yeniuyeisimtxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(153, 255, 153));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(yeniuyeyastxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(yeniuyeisimtxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(yeniuyeepostatxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 92, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(yeniuyeisimtxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(yeniuyeyastxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(yeniuyeepostatxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        yeniuyetable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        yeniuyetable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                yeniuyetableMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(yeniuyetable);

        cmd_save.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        cmd_save.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        cmd_save.setText("Kaydet");
        cmd_save.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmd_saveActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cmd_save1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        cmd_save1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        cmd_save1.setText("Sil");
        cmd_save1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmd_save1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cmd_save2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        cmd_save2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        cmd_save2.setText("Temizle");
        cmd_save2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmd_save2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cmd_save3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        cmd_save3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        cmd_save3.setText("Düzenle");
        cmd_save3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmd_save3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        cmd_save4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        cmd_save4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        cmd_save4.setText("Ana Menü");
        cmd_save4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                cmd_save4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(cmd_save2)
                            .addComponent(cmd_save))
                        .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(cmd_save1)
                            .addComponent(cmd_save3)))
                    .addComponent(cmd_save4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 617, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(36, 36, 36)
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(cmd_save)
                    .addComponent(cmd_save1))
                .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(cmd_save3)
                    .addComponent(cmd_save2))
                .addGap(59, 59, 59)
                .addComponent(cmd_save4)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 478, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        setBounds(0, 0, 866, 538);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void yeniuyeisimtxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                              

    private void yeniuyetableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          

        try{
         int row =yeniuyetable.getSelectedRow();
         String Table_click=(yeniuyetable.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
         String sql ="select * from YeniUyeFrame where İsim='"+Table_click+"' ";
         pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         rs=pst.executeQuery();
         if(rs.next()){

         String add1 =rs.getString("İsim");
         yeniuyeisimtxt.setText((rs.getString("İsim")).trim());

         String add2 =rs.getString("Yaş");
         yeniuyeyastxt.setText((rs.getString("Yaş")).trim());

         String add3 =rs.getString("EPosta");
         yeniuyeepostatxt.setText((rs.getString("EPosta")).trim());

         String add4 =rs.getString("KatılımTarihi");
         yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt.setText((rs.getString("KatılımTarihi")).trim());






         }         


        }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);



        }finally{
try{
pst.close();
rs.close();
}catch(Exception e){
}
}














    }                                         

    private void cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{
            String sql = "Insert into YeniUyeFrame (İsim,Yaş,EPosta,KatılımTarihi) values (?,?,?,?)";

            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, yeniuyeisimtxt.getText());
            pst.setString(2, yeniuyeyastxt.getText());
            pst.setString(3, yeniuyeepostatxt.getText());
            pst.setString(4, yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt.getText());


            pst.executeUpdate();

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kaydedildi!");

        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

        }finally{
try{
pst.close();
rs.close();
}catch(Exception e){
}
}

        Update_table();

    }                                        

    private void cmd_save1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

         String sql="delete from YeniUyeFrame where İsim =?";



    try{

    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    pst.setString(1, yeniuyeisimtxt.getText());

    pst.executeUpdate();

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Silindi");


    }catch(Exception e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


    }

    Update_table();








    }                                         

    private void cmd_save2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        yeniuyeisimtxt.setText("");
      yeniuyeyastxt.setText("");
      yeniuyeepostatxt.setText("");
      yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt.setText("");


    }                                         

    private void cmd_save3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

        try{

String value1=yeniuyeisimtxt.getText();
String value2=yeniuyeyastxt.getText();
String value3=yeniuyeepostatxt.getText();
String value4=yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt.getText();




 String sql="update YeniUyeFrame set İsim='"+value1+"' ,Yaş ='"+value2+"',EPosta='"+value3+"',KatılımTarihi='"+value4+"' where İsim='"+value1+"' ";
              pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
              pst.executeUpdate();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Güncellendi");



}catch(Exception e){;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);


}finally{
try{
pst.close();
rs.close();
}catch(Exception e){
}
}
  Update_table();









    }                                         

    private void cmd_save4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          

         dispose();
        SeperateMenu s = new SeperateMenu();
         s.setVisible(true);









    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YeniUye.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YeniUye.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YeniUye.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(YeniUye.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new YeniUye().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton cmd_save;
    private javax.swing.JButton cmd_save1;
    private javax.swing.JButton cmd_save2;
    private javax.swing.JButton cmd_save3;
    private javax.swing.JButton cmd_save4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField yeniuyeepostatxt;
    private javax.swing.JTextField yeniuyeisimtxt;
    private javax.swing.JTextField yeniuyekatilimtarihitxt;
    private javax.swing.JTable yeniuyetable;
    private javax.swing.JTextField yeniuyeyastxt;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

Comment: Android doesn't have Swing  library. Please describe what you want to build and remove swing code, no one will read it.

Comment: This is just a jframe . I know android doesnt have Swing library but, how can i do a table like that on android ? Or which methods should i use ? I just gave these codes for what i need to do on android.

Comment: You could use a [TableLayout](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablelayout-example/), if you're new to Android, working through the '[Getting Started](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)' examples would be a good idea.

Comment: @MaximShoustin If you dont want you cant , no one forcing you about that, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android equivilent of `JPanel is LinearLayout`

```
equivilent of JButton is Button
JLabel -> TextView
JScrollPane -> ScrollView
```

`JOptionPane -> AlertDialog or Spinner or Dialog` depending on what your app does

equivilent of `ResultSet is Cursor` -- used exactly the same as ResultSet

example:

```
Cursor c = database.query("SELECT * FROM someTable");
int someValue = c.getInt(someTableColumnIndex);
String someStringValue = c.getString(someTableOtherColumnIndex);
```

lookup: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html

but your code needs major rewrites to make it look the same on Android

Android mostly uses XML layouts, but you can use code to create your layout

example :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this,new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); //width and height

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("hello");
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"you clicked me! my text is: "+(Button)v.getText().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
});
}

}
```

If you want to build a table - Android has TableLayout
look this up: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Comment: Hmm i got it . Thanks for your answer, i think i need to find another way to do this.